# Use Section as Frametitle and Display

Tags: beamer

I would like to use \section{Name of section} which would act as
frametitle. This way it would be possible to let automatically do
latex to put a numbering and it would be done with command section.
Example:

1. Introduction %<- as frametitle on top of slide (see below)
2. Exp. Procedure %<- as frametitle on top of slide (see below)
3. Results %<- as frametitle on top of slide (see below)
4. and so on.

The second point is that by just changing the definiton of packages and header
of the part before \begin{document}, it would be possible to use the
document too for article, where \section is being used.
Well, \newcommand would be a solution maybe.

I have herewith a basic example.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item Line 1
\begin{itemize}
\item Line 2
\item Line 2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Would you have any ideas?

Thank you very much

-- 
Rgds

Answer (score 2):

You could slightly change the definition of the frametitle template (`madrid` theme uses the frametitle defined in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty`) and replace `\insertframetitle` by something like `\thesection.~\insertsection`.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\thesection.~\insertsection\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{bla}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item Line 1
\begin{itemize}
\item Line 2
\item Line 2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am very impressed. My God what a superbe, but high technology, possibility. It is far what I can understand today. Highly complex for me to understand right now the employed technology. Many thnanks. Is there maybe a package that does this maybe too?

Comment: @user342342 I don't think there is a package to do exactly this.

Comment: @samcarter is there any way how this could work automatically on each frame without the need to call `\frametitle`?

Comment: @Skillmon Yes - however the solution may require a bit of code. Can you ask a question?