# Weird behavior when using expl3 and beamer

Tags: beamer, expl3

I am trying to create a beamer template where everything is top-aligned by default. For those slides without a title, I would like to add a top margin automatically. The *CASE 2* in the MWE below is what I come up with. Unfortunately, it fails to increase top margin. In comparison, I included *CASE 1*, which works properly in terms of adding margin only. I am not sure why putting the `minipage` inside some `if` block will change the output.

**Output of CASE 1**:

[image]

**Output of CASE 2**:

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% CASE 1:
% works normally
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][1cm][t]{0.8\paperwidth}
  abc\par
  def\par
  ghi\par
  \end{minipage}  
}

% CASE 2:
% not working
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  % get frame number
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\insertframenumber}
  % do not add margin to the title page
  \tl_if_eq:NnF \l_tmpa_tl {1} {
    \cs_if_exist:NT \insertframetitle {
      \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin {\insertframetitle}
      \dim_compare:nNnT {\coffin_wd:N \l_tmpa_coffin} < {0.1pt} {
        % add spacing when there is no title
        \begin{minipage}[t][1cm][t]{0.8\paperwidth}
        abc\par
        def\par
        ghi\par
        \end{minipage}  
      }
    }
  }
}


\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{title}
conten...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And is there a particular reason to use a coffin instead of a box?

Comment: @Skillmon As I said, I want to add margins to frames without titles automatically so that the content is not so close to the top border. As for the use of l3coffins, it is merely a way to determine if the frame has a title. At this moment, I cannot figure out a more direct approach.

Comment: The coffin is meant to be a structure to be typeset/joined with other coffins with some handles. That's an unnecessary overhead if you just want to see whether something has a width when typeset. Instead you could use `\hbox_set:Nn` and `\box_wd:N` (that's all I meant with my second comment).

Comment: And should that margin have typeset contents? Or is it just some white space?

Comment: The problem is, that `\insertframetitle` isn't defined, your code is never executed. `\insertframetitle` is available in the `frametitile` template, not in `headline`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389255/insert-section-name-and-number-as-frametitle-on-each-frame/389258#389258 might be helpful here. It modifies `beamer` to use a `noframetitle` template if no frame title was given. Just change the `noframetitle` template to introduce your white space.

Comment: Thanks for a series of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This wasn't created by me, I just adapted it to fit this use case. If you think this deserves an upvote, you should really upvote the [original answer by @samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389255/insert-section-name-and-number-as-frametitle-on-each-frame/389258#389258).*

The following reuses [ideas from @samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389255/insert-section-name-and-number-as-frametitle-on-each-frame/389258#389258) (but patches the environment, like proposed there).

We patch `beamer`'s internals to add a `noframetitle` template that gets evoked when there is no `\frametitle` in a frame. This `noframetitle` template will add some white space. You can modify that template to your liking, I just put a `\rule` there with width `0pt` (so it is invisible), the height I got from trial-and-error to match the spacing of a frame with a title.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\endbeamer@frameslide
  {\setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\box\voidb@x}
  {%
    % no change for title page
    \ifnum\c@framenumber=1
      \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\box\voidb@x
    \else
      \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\vbox{%
        \vbox{}%
        {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{noframetitle}\vskip0.25em}%
      }%
    \fi
  }
  {}
  {\GenericError{}{Error: Failed to patch beamer's frameslide}{}{}}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{noframetitle}{\rule{0pt}{6.7mm}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{title}
  content\ldots
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  content\ldots
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is very clever, and you must have deep understanding with respect to how beamer works internally. I need to achieve this because I am replicating one of the existing PowerPoint templates with LaTeX. Surprisingly it is nontrivial to add some small margin.

Comment: @AlanXiang no, I don't. @samcarter has, I just know a bit about TeX programming, `beamer` is way above my head (everything is different in it because it basically has to change everything for its job). And I know your pain, I had to recreate such a template a few years ago myself (that's when I asked and @samcarter provided above hack).